# Cloud Run - gRPC authentication through service account - Java

Tags: authentication, grpc, service-accounts, google-cloud-run, grpc-java

I've deployed to Google Cloud Run (fully managed) a gRPC server with the option "Required Authentication" set to true.

I'm trying to authenticate the calls from my gRPC client through a Google Service Account, however I'm always getting below exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED: HTTP status code 401
```

Below is how I'm creating the gRPC channel and attaching the service account.

```
public GrpcClient(Channel channel) throws IOException {
    Credentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();

    blockingStub = CalculatorServiceGrpc
            .newBlockingStub(channel)
            .withCallCredentials(MoreCallCredentials.from(credentials));
}
```

Obs.: env var GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is set with the path of the SA, and the SA has Cloud Run Invoker privilege

Is there anything that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research I was able to authenticate the requests using IdTokenCredentials. See below the result.

```
public GrpcClient(Channel channel) throws IOException {
    ServiceAccountCredentials saCreds = ServiceAccountCredentials
            .fromStream(new FileInputStream("path\to\sa"));

    IdTokenCredentials tokenCredential = IdTokenCredentials.newBuilder().setIdTokenProvider(saCreds)
            .setTargetAudience("https://{projectId}-{hash}-uc.a.run.app").build();

    blockingStub = CalculatorServiceGrpc
            .newBlockingStub(channel)
            .withCallCredentials(MoreCallCredentials.from(tokenCredential));
}
```

Comment: Yeah that works, too, if you think you need to customize the service account with a file. However, Cloud Run already has a service account that it runs as, you don’t need to deliver a credentials file to it to get an ID Token or access to Google APIs.

Comment: @AhmetB-Google I think they are trying to authenticate from a service outside of GCP/cloud run, in which case you do need to load the service account (either let it pick up by default, or point to the file manually), right?

Answer (score 2):

When calling a Cloud Run server from a generic HTTP client, setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` doesn't have an effect. (*That only works when you call Google’s APIs with a Google client library.*)

Even when deployed to Cloud Run, gRPC is just HTTP/2, so authenticating to a Cloud Run service is documented at the [Service-to-Service Authentication](https://cloud.devsite.corp.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service) page. In a nutshell this involves:

- getting a JWT (identity token) from metadata service endpoint inside the container
- setting it as a header on the request to the Cloud Run app, as `Authorization: Bearer [[ID_TOKEN]]`.

In gRPC, headers are called "metadata", so you should find the equivalent gRPC Java method to set that. (It probably is a per-RPC option.)

Read about a [Go example here](https://ahmet.im/blog/grpc-auth-cloud-run/), it basically explains you that gRPC servers running on Cloud Run still authenticate the same way. In this case, also make sure to tell Java:

- you need to connect to domain:443 (not :80)
- gRPC Java needs to use machine root CA certificates to verify validity of TLS certificate presented by Cloud Run (as opposed to skipping TLS verification)

Comment: Thanks @AhmentB, actually I was able to do it using IdTokenCredentials (I'll post the code snippet in a new comment, so it gets formatted properly).

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post looking for a Python-related answer.
So for those who want to solve this problem using a Python client:

```
import google.oauth2
import google.oauth2.id_token
import google.auth
import google.auth.transport
import google.auth.transport.requests

TARGET_CHANNEL = "your-app-name.run.app:443"

token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(google.auth.transport.requests.Request(), TARGET_CHANNEL)
call_cred = grpc.access_token_call_credentials(auth.get_identification_token(
        "https://" + TARGET_CHANNEL.strip(':443')))
channel_cred = grpc.composite_channel_credentials(grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(), call_cred)
channel = grpc.secure_channel(TARGET_CHANNEL, credentials=channel_cred)`
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also running into `UNAUTHENTICATED: HTTP status code 401`.  I had a GCP Load Balancer all setup with HTTPS and a backend routing to a Cloud Run Service.  The backend service has to be HTTP2 for grpc like the above answer.  But there was one more spot that needed HTTP2.  The cloud run service needs to be setup to accept HTTP2, by default it is HTTP1.  You can use

```
gcloud run services update <SERVICE> --use-http2
```

to set the cloud run to use http2.  This will allow the load balancers backend HTTP2 to communicate with the Cloud Run Service over HTTP which grpc is required to have.

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/http2